# Datetime error using datefield

Tags: html, date, datetime, time, ext.net

I'm using ext.net 3 and i need to create datetime together but in this ext both time and date are not same.

```
 <ext:DateField runat="server" ID="date1" MarginSpec="0 10 0 20" LabelAlign="Right" Format="yyyy-MM-dd h:i:s" FieldLabel="Gate In Date/Time" AllowBlank="false" IndicatorText="*" IndicatorCls="red-text"></ext:DateField>
```

The result is 2016-06-01 12:00:00

The date works fine but the time got some problem.

Comment: what do you mean by the date got some problem ?

Comment: I mean the date works fine but the time is not. the time is always showing 12:00:00 its static never change.

Comment: is your server at the good hour ?

Comment: yes the server at the good hour

Comment: try H:i:s in your format instead of h:i:s . It's only a first checking but if it run we are on the good way.

Comment: the result show 0:00:00

Answer (score 0):

You are returning data from the DateField so the time is going to always be 12:00:00.  Ext.Net includes a TimeField as well.  It's a dropdown list of formatted times.  Use both to have your user select Date & Time.

[image]

```
        <ext:FieldContainer runat="server" FieldLabel="Pick Date & Time" Layout="HBoxLayout">
            <Items>
                <ext:DateField ID="DateField1" runat="server">

                </ext:DateField>

                <ext:ToolbarSeparator Width="5" />

                <ext:TimeField ID="Timefield1" runat="server" Width="100">

                </ext:TimeField>
            </Items>
        </ext:FieldContainer>
```